# Cleos set contract, Internal Service error timeout_exception

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos, cleos, error

I am running EOS on my laptop.
If I execute the "cleos set contract" command and the contract size is more than 200kb, I get an error:

```
error 2021-06-01T17:44:30.084 http-1    http_plugin.cpp:280           handle_exception     ] Internal Service error, http: 2 timeout_exception: deadline 2021-06-01T17:44:30.083 exceeded by 33us 
deadline 2021-06-01T17:44:30.083 exceeded by 33us 
    {"d":"2021-06-01T17:44:30.083","t":33}
    http-1  json.hpp:69 operator()
error 2021-06-01T17:44:30.089 cleos     main.cpp:4013                 main                 ] Failed with error: deadline 2021-06-01T17:44:30.083 exceeded by 33us  (2)
deadline 2021-06-01T17:44:30.083 exceeded by 33us
```

exceeded changes from 30 to 100 us.

I changed values: max-transaction-time, http-max-response-time-ms, abi-serializer-max-time-ms, max_transaction_cpu_usage in config.ini and genesis.json files and when starting nodeos, but the result does not change.

Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have increased the right limits.
it is still failing because your laptop configuration it is too slow for this transaction to execute in the block time limits (no transaction can take longer than maximum block time of 500 ms, this is not configurable, maybe in future versions...).
is your laptop CPU maxed out while running these commands/tests?
try to free up some of your local resources and then try again.